# how do I return documents back to my API call?

Tags: node.js, mean-stack

I am trying to call method `get_radar_life_cycle` from `app.get("/api/radar_cloning` and it throws the error shown below,
error is coming from line `return done(null,documents)` how do I return `documents` back to my API call?

METHODS:-

```
let get_cloned_radars = function(documents, done) { 
let complete_radar_list=[]
  for (let i = 0; i < documents.length; i++) {         
    complete_radar_list.push(documents[i]['orgRadar']);
      for (let j = 0; j < documents[i]['clonedRadarsdetailslist'].length; j++) { 
        complete_radar_list.push(documents[i]['clonedRadarsdetailslist'][j]['clonedRadar']);
      }
  }
  data = complete_radar_list 
  return done(null, data)
}

let get_radar_life_cycle = function(data,done) {
   console.log("data after get_radar_life_cycle") 
   console.log(data)
   Radar_life_cycle.find({orgRadar: {$in:data}})
   .then(documents => {
    console.log(documents) --> shows correct data
    });
  return done(null,documents) --> Error is coming from this line
 };
```

API call:

```
 app.get("/api/radar_cloning", (req, res, next) => {
   Radar_cloning.find({orgRadar: {$in:req.query.params.split(',')}})
   .then(documents => {
      get_cloned_radars(documents, function(err,data) { 
      if (err) {
        res.json(err);
      if (data!=null){
        console.log(data)
        }//end for data
      }//end of (Err)
    });//get_cloned_radars

      get_radar_life_cycle(data, function(err,radar_life_cycle_data) { 
      if (err) {
        res.json(err);
        console.log(radar_life_cycle_data)
        }//end for radar_life_cycle_data
      }//end of (Err)
  });//end of get_radar_life_cycle
});
 });
```

ERROR:-

```
(node:10065) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: documents is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access documents outside of its scope, the scope being everything between the `{` and `}`. So you cannot access it below the `.then(() => {})` scope.

Luckily you are are providing a callback function called `done(err, radar_life_cycle_data)`, which you can use anywhere in the scope of the `get_radar_life_cycle(documents, done)` function. Even the scopes inside of its scope. When you are calling the done function, what you are basically doing is calling this function (well it has some syntax errors, so I cleaned it up)

```
function(err,radar_life_cycle_data) { 
    if (err) {
        res.json(err);
        console.log(radar_life_cycle_data)
    }
}//end for radar_life_cycle_data
```

which then gets executed

**So the solution:**

Move your done in your `.then(() => {})` scope like this:

```
let get_radar_life_cycle = function(data,done) {
    console.log("data after get_radar_life_cycle") 
    console.log(data)
    Radar_life_cycle.find({orgRadar: {$in:data}})
    .then(documents => {
        console.log(documents) // --> shows correct data
        done(null,documents) // --> No error coming from this line
    });
};
```

Same goes for the `data` it is not in the scope of the get_cloned_radars

```
app.get("/api/radar_cloning", (req, res, next) => {
    Radar_cloning.find({orgRadar: {$in:req.query.params.split(',')}})
    .then(documents => {
        get_cloned_radars(documents, function(err,data) { 
            if (err) {
                res.json(err);
                if (data!=null) {
                    console.log(data)
                    get_radar_life_cycle(data, function(err,radar_life_cycle_data) { 
                        if (err) {
                            res.json(err);
                            console.log(radar_life_cycle_data)
                         } //end of (Err)
                    }); //end of get_radar_life_cycle
                } //end for data
            } //end of (Err)
    }); //get_cloned_radars
 });
```

But since your code is unreadable, here is a cleaned up version:

```
app.get("/api/radar_cloning", (req, res, next) => {
    const radar_life_cycle_cb = function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.json(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log(data);
    }

    const cloned_radar_cb = function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.json(err);
            return;
        }
        if (data != null) {
            get_radar_life_cycle(data, radar_life_cycle_cb);
        }
    };

    Radar_cloning.find({orgRadar: {$in:req.query.params.split(',')}})
    .then(documents => get_cloned_radars(documents, cloned_radar_cb));
}
```